# "Plain English" website Terms & Conditions

Tags: terms-of-service, disclaimers

I'm attempting to launch a website - to be specific a job portal.

There will be two target users: 1 - Employees, 2 - Job Seekers

I wish to offer a plain English Terms of Service/Terms and Conditions/Whatever that:

- Is written in as few words as possible (with each sentence written in
  plain English making this alone a challenge)
- Covers me with regard to the data protection act (The users agree to
  the storage of their data for the stated purpose ( - to find
  employees/to find work)
- Makes it clear that explicit material, jobs, descriptions etc. are
  not permitted and that they may be legally held accountable for
  non-compliance with this point
- Does not make me liable for the availability/unavailability/functions
  offered or errors
- Informs users that misuse/abuse of the portal may be legally
  accountable
- Includes something obvious that I've missed

Could anyone please point me to any resources or examples of such a 'Plain English Agreement/Disclaimer'?

Comment: Are you asking for LSE users to write the TOS for you?

Comment: It looked that way prior to my Edit - I was so caught up with finding appropriate tags for the question that I overlooked the fact that the question was not clearly stating what assistance I require.  I'm new to the Law site after years of asking and contributing on software site where yes, we point users to useful resources or even give them the answer directly.  Any assistance would be appreciated (links to guides or a pre-written TOS)

Comment: No one here will write the TOS for you; that's giving legal advice and is off-topic. See http://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer." You can Google for a plain English template of a TOS to get an idea of how they are written. But if you're starting a commercial website, for your own protection, you really need to have your own attorney draw up a TOS.

Comment: Understood, but I wish to avoid legaleese which an attorney will not.  I wish to have a 'good faith' TOS that the average person (someone like me and other non law scholars) can understand - understand.  Google did not help me with this.

Comment: Did your attorney refuse to draft in plain English? See http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/is-legalese-necessary

Comment: @KenAlton a good attorney who is sympathetic to your desires will indeed draft terms of service in plain English.  Do you imagine that somehow every plain English legal text was drafted by a non-lawyer?  On the contrary, I rather suspect that they were all drafted by lawyers.  It's *more challenging* to write legally effective texts while avoiding legalese, so a good lawyer would be *more of an asset* in such a project, not less.